# Locating TD position by it's TH, domCrawler

Tags: php, web-scraping, domcrawler

I am trying to scrape `table`'s `td` tag, but first I need to check `th`. For example let say table structure is like below.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <th>color</th>
      <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>price</th>
      <td>23.267$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>brand</th>
      <td>mustang</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this table I need to scrape `mustang` value. But I can't use `$crawler->filter('table td')->eq(3);` for that. Because position is always changing. So I need to catch the value by it's `th`. I mean if `th`'s value is **brand** then get it's `td`

what is the best way to this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I posted it as an answer. please check it out. @blueenvelope

Comment: Does domcrawler support :contains? If so it's `th:contains("brand") + td`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a best solution, but I solved it with this:

```
$props = $node->filter("table th")->each(function($th, $i){
    return $th->text();
});
$vals = $node->filter("table td")->each(function($td, $i){
    return $td->text();
});

$items = [
    "brand" => "", 
    "color" => "",
];

for ($a=0; $a < count($props); $a++) { 
    switch ($props[$a]) {
        case 'brand':
            $items["brand"] = $vals[$a];
            break;                        
    }
}
```

If there is another way or much better way to achieve this. Please feel free to post it here. Thank you.